# Slope-demarcated PlotStyle implementation

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, functions, mesh

[image: Graph]

In the above graph, I would like to display plots with slope-dependent plot styles (solid, dashed and dotted).

Specifically, the regions **a---b1**, **a---b2** and **a---b3** with solid lines(`Thick`), then **b1---c1**, **b2---c2** and **b3---c3** with `Dashed` lines and beyond c1, c2 and c3 with `DotDashed` lines.

> Is there a way to do this in a automated fashion without putting the
> coordinate points manually?

I'm using **Mathematica 12.0**.

The following code generates the above graph:

```
Plot[{2 + Sinc[x], 2 + Sinc[0.9 x], 2 + Sinc[0.8 x]}, {x, 0, 10}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Black}, PlotRange -> {1.6, 3.2}]
```

Comment: Why should lines beyond c be `DotDashed` if they have the same (negative) slope as the regions a–b which are `Thick`? This does not completely correspond to the title of your question :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"];

g[f_] := FindRoot[D[f, x], {x, #}] & /@ Range[-0.11, 10, 1] // 
    Values // Chop // Flatten;
funcs = {2 + Sinc[x], 2 + Sinc[0.9 x], 2 + Sinc[0.8 x]};
flatAt = g /@ funcs // Map[Chop] // Map[Round[#, 0.0001] &] // 
    Map[Union] // Map[Select[# >= 0 &]] // Map[Take[#, 3] &];
styles = {Red, Darker@Green, Blue};

Show@
 MapThread[
  Plot[#1
    , {x, 0, 12}
    , PlotRange -> {1.6, 3.2}
    , Mesh -> {#2}
    , MeshShading -> {Dotted, Automatic, Dashed}
    , PlotStyle -> #3
    , ImageSize -> 400
    ] &
  , {funcs, flatAt, styles}
  ]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It's beautiful. However, I want to know what I should do if I have to plot the same thing without the functions but with data table

Comment: That will be a separate question. It will involve making a smooth function by interpolating the points and then you can use it to find slopes. It depends on the highest frequency in your data. It is hard to generalize answers to such problems.

Comment: I have asked another question https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/284600/84456

Answer (score 4):

```
funcs = Function[x, #] & /@ {2 + Sinc[x], 2 + Sinc[0.9 x], 2 + Sinc[0.8 x]};

styles = {Red, Blue, Black};

meshshading = {Dashing[{}], Dashed, DotDashed};


ClearAll[xMesh]
xMesh[from_, to_] := NSolveValues[{#'[t] == 0, from <= t < to}, t] &


gridlines = Join @@ MapThread[Thread @* List][{xMesh[0, 10] /@ funcs, styles}];

Show[MapThread[
   Plot[# @ x, {x, 0, 10}, 
     Mesh -> {xMesh[0, 10] @ #}, 
     PlotStyle -> #2,  
     MeshShading -> meshshading] &] @
  {funcs, styles}, 
 GridLines -> {gridlines, None}, 
 PlotRange -> {1.6, 3.2}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 1.6}]
```

[image]

Replace `{x, 0, 10}` with `{x, 0, 20}` and `xMesh[0, 10]` with `xMesh[0, 20]` (and add the option `PlotRange -> All` to `Plot[...]`) to get

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Using [`ConditionalExpression`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConditionalExpression.html)

```
Clear["Global`*"]

funcs = {2 + Sinc[x], 2 + Sinc[0.9 x], 2 + Sinc[0.8 x]} // Rationalize;

minPts = {#[[2, 1, -1]], #[[1]]} & /@
   (Minimize[{#, 0 < x < 10}, x] & /@ funcs);

maxPts = {#[[2, 1, -1]], #[[1]]} & /@
   (Maximize[{#[[1]], #[[2]] < x < 10}, x] & /@
     Transpose[{funcs, minPts[[All, 1]]}]);

colors = {Red, Blue, Darker@Green};

lines = {Automatic, Dashed, Dotted};

styles = Flatten[Outer[{#1, #2} &, lines, colors], 1];

funcs2 = Flatten[
   Transpose[
    Tooltip[#, #[[1]]] & /@ {
        ConditionalExpression[#[[1]], 0 <= x <= #[[2]]],
        ConditionalExpression[#[[1]], #[[2]] < x <= #[[3]]],
        ConditionalExpression[#[[1]], #[[3]] < x <= 10]} & /@
     Transpose[{funcs, minPts[[All, 1]], maxPts[[All, 1]]}]]];
```

Plotting,

```
Plot[Evaluate@funcs2, {x, 0, 10},
 PlotRange -> {1.6, Automatic},
 PlotStyle -> styles,
 AxesLabel -> {Style[x, 14], None},
 Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize[4],
   {#[[1]], Tooltip[Point[#[[2]]], N[#[[2]]]], 
      Text[#[[3]], #[[2]], {0, 2}]} & /@ 
    Transpose[{colors, minPts, Subscript["b", #] & /@ 
     Range[Length@funcs]}],
   {#[[1]], Tooltip[Point[#[[2]]], N[#[[2]]]], 
      Text[#[[3]], #[[2]], {0, -2}]} & /@ 
    Transpose[{colors, maxPts, Subscript["c", #] & /@ 
     Range[Length@funcs]}]}]
```

[image]