# Slope-demarcated PlotStyle implementation (II)

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, calculus-and-analysis, functions, mesh

```
A = Table[{x, 2 + Sinc[x], 2 + Sinc[0.9 x], 2 + Sinc[0.8 x]}, {x, 0, 
     10.0, 0.1}] // N;
ListLinePlot[A[[All, {1, #}]] & /@ {2, 3, 4}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Black}, PlotRange -> {1.6, 3.2}]
```

[image]

In the above graph, I want to show the curves with slope-dependent `PlotStyles` (solid, dashed and dotted).

Specifically, the regions **a---b1**, **a---b2** and **a---b3** with solid lines(`Thick`), then **b1---c1**, **b2---c2** and **b3---c3** with `Dashed` lines and beyond c1, c2 and c3 with `Dotted` lines.

I have asked a [similar question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/284595/84456) with a beautiful [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/284598/84456). However, this question is different as here, instead of functions, we have a data table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can still use the same method if you define interpolating functions like:

```
dat = Table[{x, 2 + Sinc[x], 2 + Sinc[0.9 x], 2 + Sinc[0.8 x]}, {x, 0,
     10.0, 0.1}];
funcs = Interpolation[Transpose[{dat[[All, 1]], #}]] & /@ 
  Transpose[dat[[All, 2 ;;]]]
```

Now you may use your old code with some minor changes. Note that you will get some warning messages about interpolating functions used outside of their domain.

```
g[f_] := 
  FindRoot[D[f[x], x], {x, #}] & /@ Range[0, 10, 2] // Values // 
    Chop // Flatten;

flatAt = 
  g /@ funcs // Map[Chop] // Map[Round[#, 0.0001] &] // Map[Union] // 
    Map[Select[# >= 0 &]] // Map[Take[#, 3] &];
styles = {Red, Darker@Green, Blue};

Show@MapThread[
  Plot[#1[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> {0, 3.2}, Mesh -> {#2}, 
    MeshShading -> {Dotted, Automatic, Dashed}, PlotStyle -> #3, 
    ImageSize -> 400] &, {funcs, flatAt, styles}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**Using `Differences` and `SplitBy`:**

```
A = Table[{x, 2 + Sinc[x], 2 + Sinc[0.9 x], 2 + Sinc[0.8 x]}, {x, 0, 
     10.5, 0.1}] // N;
tA = Transpose@A;
```

If we take the `Differences` of a list and notice where the `Sign` changes, it can give a good indication of the slope going to zero. However, `Sign` returns {-1, 0, 1} as outputs, so for flat portions, once has to choose a transition resulting in a slight bias for very low frequency signals. `Interpolation` method, being continuous, (shown by @Daniel Huber) will not have this limitation.

The list of points can be `SplitBy` the criteria `Positive` before `TakeList` extracts appropriate chunks of each list to plot.

```
g[k_List] := SplitBy[Differences[k], Positive] // Map[Length];

p1 = TakeList[{tA[[1]], tA[[2]]} // Transpose, g[tA[[2]]]];
p2 = TakeList[{tA[[1]], tA[[3]]} // Transpose, g[tA[[3]]]];
p3 = TakeList[{tA[[1]], tA[[4]]} // Transpose, g[tA[[4]]]];
cols = {Red, Darker@Green, Blue};

Show@MapThread[
  ListLinePlot[ #1
    , PlotStyle -> {
      {#2, Thick}
      , {#2, Dashed}
      , {#2, Dotted}
      }
    , PlotRange -> {1.6, 3.2}
    , ImageSize -> 400
    ] &,
  {{p1, p2, p3}, cols}
  ]
```

[image]

If there are more zero-slope points or even a different number of such points per signal then the uniformity of length expected of the `MapThread` arguments will break down.

Answer (score 3):

```
data = A[[All, {1,#}]] & /@ {2,3,4};

styles = {Red, Blue, Black};
```

A function to identify peaks and troughs:

```
pt = Riffle @@ Sort[FindPeaks[#][[All, 1]]& /@ {#, -#}] & /@ Rest[Transpose@A]
```

Use `pt` to construct settings for the option `Mesh`:

```
meshspecs = MapThread[#[[#2, 1]] &] @ {data, pt /@ Rest[Transpose @ A]};

options = {MeshStyle -> Opacity[0], 
   MeshShading -> {Dashing[{}], Dashed, DotDashed}, 
   PlotRange -> {1.6, 3.2}, ImageSize -> Large};

Show[
 MapThread[ListLinePlot[#, Mesh -> {#2}, PlotStyle -> #3, options] &]@
  {data, Rest /@ meshspecs, styles}, 
 GridLines -> {Join @@ MapThread[Thread@{##} &]@{meshspecs, styles}, None}]
```

[image]